# IP warming basic

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, ip-warming

I am conducting ip warming first time.
It is a quite basic inquiry, but for clarification purposes, your kind response would be highly appreciated.

1. When I am conducting IP warming, do I have to send emails 'every day'?
2. Usually, IP warming is conducted over a period of 30 days. However, if the maximum sending volume is not high, it is possible to execute it over a shorter period.
3. Once the IP warming process is completed, is it correct that maintaining a consistent volume of emails sent ***per month,*** even if the daily sending volume is not high, will help maintain IP reputation? I was indicated that I should send between 100,000 to 250,000 emails per month with dedicated ip.
4. Additionally, as far as I know, when I get my Marketing Cloud account, I use a shared IP initially when I set up SAP. After a certain period of time, when my sending volume increases, I can request a dedicated IP from Salesforce support without any additional charge, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your questions in reverse order. Why? Since if you are using shared IP, and especially if your volumes are quite low, IP warmup should not be necessary. At least not in full scale - so ramping up your volumes over 2 weeks, should be OK in this case (and below points do not really apply for shared IPs).

You should not send emails every day when warming up your IP. I will recommend doing 2-3 batches weekly, depending on your volumes. I write about IP warmup planning in [my article here](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/deliverability/ip-warming-marketing-cloud/) - which also provides best practices and recommendations for monitoring the performance of your warmup.

If your volume goes beyond 100.000 per month, you will need to purchase dedicated IP SKU, even when not originally utilising the dedicated IP bundled in your SAP SKU. This is due to the SAP being a bundle, which can't be split up. And when you are using a dedicated IP, you should indeed maintain at least a volume of 100.000 (preferably more) emails per month to keep it warm.

Comment: Thanks, @LukasLunow. 

I apologize for the confusion. The fourth question was an additional inquiry made for clarification on a simple curiosity.

I am currently using a dedicated IP and am on the verge of initiating the IP warming process. 

Based on your response:

1. (NO) Contrary to what I thought, it is not advisable to send emails 'every day'; instead, it is better to batch send 2-3 times a week.
2. (According to your blog post, YES) It is recommended to gradually scale up from 0 to the total volume.

Comment: 3. (YES) After warming up, the IP will remain warmed when sending over 100,000 emails per month, regardless of the daily sending volume.
4. (YES) Since dedicated IP is included in the SAP SKU, it can be used later even if not initially utilized.


Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @MinkyeongKwon 4 should be NO. You can’t use dedicated IP from SAP if it was originally configured with a shared IP. You need to buy dedicated IP SKU later on.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! Now it's clear now.